# how to show call screen while android app running on background

Tags: android, screen, call, sip, launch

Im making a SIP application for android 2.3.3. I can call someone and my "incoming call screen" is shown when some calls me. But when my app is running on the background and someone calls me , the "call screen" isn't been launched. so how can I make it launch like a normal incoming call.

**FIXED:**

Manifest: add the following code in application tag

```
  <receiver android:name=".ReceiverTest" android:enabled="true">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.example.INCOMING_CALL" />
             </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Receiver class: when I receive a call, it will open my Incomingcall page

```
public class ReceiverTest extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {  
        ...
        Intent nextPage= new Intent("com.example.IncomingPage");
        nextPage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        arg0.startActivity(nextPage);   
            ...     
    }

}
```

Comment: are you talking about incoming SIP calls or VOICE calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an Activity your app is not running the background.  When a new activity is brought to the top of the stack your application is paused and placed in the background.  To allow your application to receive any type of notification try running a service or create a broadcast receiver to pick up the intents you want to listen for.  This allows your app to process while it is not on the top of the stack.

**UPDATE**

So you have registered a broadcast receiver... this is good... but... If you registered it in your activity and the activity is killed, so is the reference and vm of your application and the intent is not received.  Try making your broadcast receiver independent of the activity (ie make it be invoked by the system using the manifest).  Then your broadcast receiver can receive intents even when your application is dead, and launch what you need.

The alternative is make a service that registers your receiver - a service can run in the background but then you have to worry about making your service light enough to never be killed (more tricks to this).  The best best is option 1 (way less overhead).

Comment: I think you didn't understand me or I didnt you. let me explain thiş way. I run my app, after that I register my broadcast receiver to receive the incoming calls, it works perfectly while im in my app. And if I press the "Home button" my app goes to background but i still can receive calls , and now comes the problem , I want my app come to the screen so I can reject or accept the call.

Comment: I get what you are saying.  Your call screen is not being shown when someone calls you when your application is running in the background.  Again... applications running in the background are for all purposes "dead" unless there is a broadcast receiver that will get the intent of an incoming call, or a service that is detecting it. Read the update for more info....

Comment: oh, now I know what you mean , thank you and sry for my understanding